# Redirecting most of site https to http apart from one section

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site and we only want https to work on the billing section as that is currently the only section that is setup to work with it, so we want to make sure if anyone goes to `https` on any other part of the site then they will be redirected to the `http` equivalent.

Currently we are only doing this for one page, here is the current `.htaccess` file from the root of the site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^auction_search.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/auction_search.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*)$ $2.php?rewrite_params=$1&page_url=$2

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/?$ shop.php?shop_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/ajax_files/watch_item\.php$ ajax_files/watch_item.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/ajax_files/save_field\.php$ ajax_files/save_field.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/([0-9a-z.-]+)/images/form-cb-icons\.png$ images/form-cb-icons.png [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^group-break/([0-9]+)/[0-9a-z.-]+/?$ group_break.php?cb_id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^group-breaks/([a-z]+)-[a-z-]+/?$ group_breaks.php?tab=$1 [L,NC]
```

As you can see near the top there is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^auction_search.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/auction_search.php [R=301,L]
```

So we want to change this so it redirects all `https` requests to the equivalent `http` page APART from anything INSIDE and INCLUDING the directory `billing` which runs off the main root ie; it's location is: `www.mysite.com/billing/`

**Edit:** It actually should ALLOW the following extensions to be viewed over `https` too: .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .css, .js

So just wondering how we can change that current rule we have to do what we want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule right at the same place:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^billing(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: So I just replace the other rule with this one?

Comment: No, `auction_search` should be treated the same as any other page outside the billing area.

Comment: One question - how come this one has the additional flags `NC,NE` on it?

Comment: `NC` is for ignore case and `NE` for no encoding. That is needed if your original URL has some special characters like brackets or space etc.

Comment: Sorry, just made an edit to my post as it is causing a warning icon in the billing area because now it is loading insecure assets. So wondering if it actually could ALLOW the following extensions to be viewed over `https` too: .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .css, .js - this should fix the warning icon in the billing are as then they will be able to be requested by https.

Comment: ok I made an edit in the answer, going offline for some work, will check back this thread in couple of hours.